# Why does this command delete a remote branch? git push origin :branchName

Tags: git, unix

Git push origin branchName, will update a remote branch. 
Git push origin :branchName, will delete a remote branch without warning.

Why is this so? What does colon mean in this context? Is it used anywhere else like this?

Comment: `push a:b` means “push `a` to `b`”, so `push :b` means “push nothing to `b`”. From git-push(1): “Pushing an empty <src> allows you to delete the <dst> ref from the remote repository.”

Comment: Because it's specified and implemented that way: see the [git-push man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-codegitpushoriginexperimentalcode)