# Conditionally delete a remote branch using `git push origin :branch-name` ... but only if branch exists?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-branch

**The short version of my question:**

Is there a way to conditionally delete a remote branch using `git push origin :gh-pages` where the command is skipped or ignored if the gh-pages branch doesn't exist?

**The long version of my question:**

I'm building a boilerplate / starter template for using NPM as a Build System or Workflow for building basic webpages (instead of using something like Grunt or Gulp). The project uses a `/build` folder and I wanted to use Github Pages to serve the contents of `/build`. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that from /settings (I only see /root, not /build), so I ran across this command:

`git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages`

Which creates a `gh-pages` branch and pushes my changes from the `/build` folder of my master branch to the newly created `gh-pages` branch. Excellent!

Unfortunately, I can't simply update my `gh-pages` branch with changes (nor would I want to). I also can't make changes in `master` and then merge them into `gh-pages`. I get lots of error messages with branches being unrelated, or out of sync, or whatever.

Instead I need to make the changes in `master` and then use the `git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages` command again to push those changes. But I run into another error where it doesn't want to push new changes into an existing `gh-pages` branch.

Okay ... So to fix this I added `git push origin :gh-pages` to my command. So now my "deploy" command in my package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "deploy": "git push origin :gh-pages && git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages",
    ...
  },
```

This works great. I simply type `npm run deploy` in my terminal and `git push origin :gh-pages` deletes the existing `gh-pages` branch and `git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages` creates a new `gh-pages` branch with my changes. Excellent!

But ... the final problem I can't seem to figure out is this. If it's the first time running the deploy command, the gh-pages branch won't exist and my deploy script fails.

So is there a way to conditionally run the `git push origin :gh-pages` part? Something like `if origin gh-pages exists ... git push origin :gh-pages`?

By the way, deleting a branch this way (using a leading colon) was totally new to me. And the [git-push man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-codegitpushoriginexperimentalcode) didn't explain it well. To understand how `git push origin :gh-pages` results in deleting the `gh-pages` branch, take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657462/why-does-this-command-delete-a-remote-branch-git-push-origin-branchname).

In case it might be helpful, heres the [repo](https://github.com/tyleryoungblood/npm-workflow). The package.json file is where the deploy script is located.

Comment: Also, the original solution came from https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-1851849. I wanted to post it to both give credit to @mikeyhogarth and to provide additional context in case someone else is struggling with the same problem and was wondering where I initially found the partial solution.

Comment: `git branch -r|grep origin/gh-pages`

Comment: `git push` docs [explains](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) `:gh-pages` in great details. Your case is "*Pushing an empty <src> allows you to delete the <dst> ref from the remote repository.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* simply invoke the push-to-delete and continue anyway if it fails.  This is crude—it would be better to continue if and only if it fails due to the branch not existing—but serviceable.  To continue even if the command fails, use `git push origin :gh-pages; git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages`.

I would not recommend this method though (with or without something more clever to detect a "desirable failure").  There's another solution in that same [comment thread you linked](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-1851849) in [your own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947717/conditionally-delete-a-remote-branch-using-git-push-origin-branch-name-bu/65949740#comment116600858_65947717) that mentions this method:

> ```
> git push origin `git subtree split --prefix build_folder master`:gh-pages --force
> ```

which is a bit shorter and simpler.  Note that this uses `build_folder` rather than `build`; if we make it match, and use the `+` syntax to implement the forced push and the `$(...)` syntax that I find nicer than the backquote syntax, we get:

```
git push origin +$(git subtree split --prefix build master):gh-pages
```

If there is some chance that the `git subtree split` itself will fail, use:

```
hash=$(git subtree split --prefix build master) && git push origin +$hash:gh-pages
```

If you would like a local branch named `gh-pages`, use:

```
hash=$(git subtree split --prefix build master) && git branch -f gh_pages $hash && git push -f origin gh-pages
```

for instance.